# xlsxwriter issues using python 3.3 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Struggling to get xlxswriter to create multiple worksheets and use the pandas df.to_excel method to place the data in there.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlsxwriter
import os as os
import sqlite3 as sql
import xlrd

path = (r'C:\Users\test1\Downloads\category.xlsx') #folder

data = pd.DataFrame()
data = pd.read_excel(path,sheetname='1')
print (data.shape)
data.head()

#create excel workbook using xlsxwriter
#workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hyperlink.xlsx')
writer = ExcelWriter('hyperlink.xlsx')
data.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
workbook.close()
```

Comment: the answer was to change the engine - http://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.org/pandas.html